# how to pass data from one activity to another in android studio?

Tags: android

I have a scenario where after logging in through a login page, there will be activity which takes some input values from user and there is a next button.Then there is another activity and this takes some more values from user.this page has submit button.After submitting app will collect the data from activity1 and activity 2..and gives some corresponding result.
But I am not passing the values which is entered by user from 1st activity to 2nd activity..

Comment: Why did you specify "Android Studio"? This is a question about the OS, the IDE doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Intent` class. and `putExtra` with values you desire.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: ok..I do this..and inform later on ..thanks..